# MVC Displaying name of logged in user in nav bar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, menubar

I'm using twitter bootstrap package in my application for my app layout.
I mostly use _BootstrapLayout.basic.cshtml as my default layout.

```
@using System.Web.Optimization
@using BootstrapSupport
@using NavigationRoutes
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="@Styles.Url("~/content/css")" rel="stylesheet"/>
        @RenderSection("head", required: false)
        @RenderSection("jtable", required:false)
        @Html.Partial("_html5shiv")
        @* favicons and touch icons go here *@
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="brand" href="#" title="change in _bootstrapLayout.basic.cshtml">Sorama</a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            @Html.Navigation()
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
        <div class="container">
            @Html.Partial("_alerts")
            @Html.Partial("_validationSummary")
            @RenderBody()   
            <hr>
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; Sorama @System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy")</p>
            </footer> 
        </div>
         @Scripts.Render("~/js")
         @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

this gives me a page with nav bar 
[image]

How can i show the Welcome message to the logged in User on the right corner of the nav bar? Something like Welcome ABC! and some log off option on side?
The only thing I know is i can get name of current user from `User.Identity.Name` but I don't know how to make it appear on menu bar.
I couldn't find something that could help me so I thought may be I could get it here.

**Edit**: After `@User.Identity.Name` being added in view
I added above mentioned code after `<ul>` tag with `@html.navigation`
and this is what I get
[image]

I get the Welcome Demo on menu bar(next to profile, difficult to see) but it is nothing like I expected.
Could something be done in `DefaultRouteConfig` provided by Bootstrap?

```
 public class LayoutsRouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapNavigationRoute<ModuleController>("Module", c => c.Index());
            routes.MapNavigationRoute<AccountController>("Hardware", c => c.Login());
            routes.MapNavigationRoute<LayoutsController>("Profile", c => c.Starter())
                  .AddChildRoute<LayoutsController>("Change Password", c => c.Marketing())
                  .AddChildRoute<AccountController>("Add User", c => c.Register())
                  .AddChildRoute<LayoutsController>("Logout", c => c.SignIn())
                ;

        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You're more likely to get an answer to a specific question, rather than asking "show me how to do X".

Comment: I know I can get name of current user from `User.Identity.Name` but I don't know how to display it in menu bar on the right side. My mind is in blank state for this implementation.

Comment: How much knowledge of twitter bootstrap do you have? Have a look inside the @Html.Navigation razor extension.

Comment: What Bootstrap package did you install? There's some that offer Razor helpers and such, but none of them should have done anything with routes.

Comment: its called `Twitter Bootstrap for Asp.Net MVC4 sample` it is the extended version of `Bootstrap for MVC 4` which works on empty application and adds some cool controller and `ExampleLayoutRouteConfig` like i mentioned in my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the div element that contains the nav, just add another div element and put the username in there.

Something like:

```
<div>@User.Identity.Name</div>
```

`ul` tag is styled for Bootstrap navigation so creating a

```
<li> <a href="#"> @User.Identity.Name</a></li>
```

should look ok and you can use action link to user management instead of `#`

Comment: I've done what you've mentioned. I've posted the result as edit. Works, but not as expected. Looks funny right now :)

Comment: You'll need to add styles to it to make it look how you want. How well do you know bootstrap, CSS etc...  It might be worth looking for some bootstrap examples. As we don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve its hard to answer styling questions. Maybe add a screen shot of what you are getting and what you want to achieve.