# How to add more user data to ASP.NET MVC user.Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How can I extend or add more methods to the user identity?

When a user is registered, in the header nav, the username is specified to be the user email. How can I customized the user identity to add more data eg. `User.Identity.GetFullname()`. I am using ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC Displaying name of logged in user in nav bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17214701/mvc-displaying-name-of-logged-in-user-in-nav-bar)

Comment: I am not having issues to display data. My problem is to add like a 'Fullname' field in the user identity and display is in the navbar instead of their email.

Comment: You extend `IdentityUser` as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335353/how-to-extend-available-properties-of-user-identity?rq=1 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.0#custom-user-data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extend available properties of User.Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335353/how-to-extend-available-properties-of-user-identity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to add more fields to your IdentityUser, then you can just simply extend it with a help of a class.

For example, create a new class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser{

   public string FullName { get; set;}

}
```

When will you apply the migrations to your database you'll see that there will be an extra column which is **FullName**.

You **shouldn't** recreate the properties which are already stored in your existing AspNetUsers table.(Ex: Id, Email, Username etc..) Because this will **not** regenerate your whole table but just adds the new columns to the AspNetUsers table.

But there is **another** approach, and this part is important I think.

Lets assume that you have a `Product.cs` :

```
public class Product {
   public int Id { get; set;}
   public string ProductNo { get; set; } 
   public string ProductName { get; set;}
}
```

and you **have already** using a `DbContext` to apply your migrations about your Product Model.

Possible `DbContext.cs` would be :

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
       optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=YourServer; Database=DbName; integrated security=true;");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         //This can be used.  
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

And in general, your `DataContext` for your `ApplicationUser` would be like this:

```
public class ApplicationIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
   public ApplicationIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationIdentityDbContext> options) : base(options){}
}
```

This is a simple way of creating Data Contexts. But when you would like to define a relationship with those 2 tables(Products and AspNetUsers), It can be a relation where all the **users** have his/her own `Product`, then high possibility you'll get an error or you wont be able to control 2 different DataContexts.

So, for avoiding these kind of struggles, using only **1** Data Context would be a better solution and it should look like this:

```
public class DataContext: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
}
```

Now you can simply define **ForeignKeys** between your `ApplicationUser` and `Product`.

For example:

```
public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser{
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public int? ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```